# VBA lookup with multiple returns

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am looking for help with applying VLOOKUP function to add extension to my pre existing table,

TABLE 1:

| CAR | TOP SPEED | COLOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | 200 | BLACK |
| TESLA | 220 | WHITE |

Table 2:

| CAR | MODEL | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FORD | MUSTANG | 2022 |
| BMW | X5 | 2020 |
| HONDA | ACCORD | 2019 |
| TESLA | Model S | 2021 |
| NISSAN | MAXIMA | 2017 |

I am aiming to have the Table B as follows:

| CAR | TOP SPEED | COLOR | MODEL | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | 200 | BLACK | X5 | 2020 |
| TESLA | 220 | WHITE | Model S | 2021 |

```
sub CARSPEC()

Dim R As Long
Dim C As Long
Table1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Sheets("Sheet1").cells(rows.count,1).end(XLUP).row) 
Table2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:H" & Sheets("Sheet1").cells(rows.count,1).end(XLUP).row)
R = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Row 
C = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Column
For Each cell In Table1
 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, C) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell, Table2, 2, False)
 R = R + 1
Next cell

End sub
```

With the code above I am only getting the table without the year, meaning :

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | 200 | BLACK | X5 |
| TESLA | 220 | WHITE | Model S |

How could I expand the return values to cover the years as well.

Very much appreciated and THX Ahead.

Comment: Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, C) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell, Table2, 2, False)    I am looking to change he column index to cover 2 and 3, but not sure about the syntax for the idea.

Comment: `Table2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:H" & Sheets("Sheet1").` Sheet 1 ??

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub CARSPEC()

    Dim lastrow As Long, awf
    Dim Table1 As Range, Table2 As Range, cell As Range
    
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Table2 = .Range("A2:H" & lastrow)
    End With
    
    Set awf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Table1 = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
       
        For Each cell In Table1
            .Cells(cell.Row, "D") = awf.VLookup(cell.Value, Table2, 2, False)
            .Cells(cell.Row, "E") = awf.VLookup(cell.Value, Table2, 3, False)
        Next
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx a lot Buddy for the correct code, I was about on the same track except my code looks really beginner. but definitely I will be using yours.

Comment: Here is my old fashion code, but it was working, but I can say I learnt something new from you. thx again

Answer (score 0):

```
'R = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 9).Row
'C = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 9).Column
'R1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 10).Row
'C1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 10).Column
'R2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 11).Row
'C2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 11).Column

    
    
    'For Each cl In Table1
       
 
        'Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 3, 0)
        'Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
        'Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Dept_Row1, Dept_Clm1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 4, 0)
        'Dept_Row1 = Dept_Row1 + 1
        'Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Dept_Row2, Dept_Clm2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 5, 0)
        'Dept_Row2 = Dept_Row2 + 1
    'Next c1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).